# UVCCamera with samples, how import to android studio?

Tags: android, android-camera, lib, ndk-build, uvc

I want work with usb camera (uvc) and Android Studio (Windows). I am having problems with the USB cam library "libuvccamera". I want to know how solve the problems or any another way to get the view of the usb cam in my app. Let me explain better what´s happening:

I tested the USB cam with CameraFi app ( https://www.camerafi.com/apps/ )and the usb camera is recognized by the Android system (and working ok).

After do a search to work with uvc (usb) cams in Android Studio, I see that I can use this library: https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera.

After downloading this library + examples, I tried opening with Android Studio (simply by opening builg.gradle), the code looks ok but when I try run usbCameraTest0 (or any other example), ***the build failed with (I attach the build output)***:

*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.*

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':libuvccamera:ndkBuild'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build.cmd''
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
14 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 7 up-to-date

=> **If run with --stacktrace option I get:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':libuvccamera:ndkBuild'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build.cmd''

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':libuvccamera:ndkBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:163)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build.cmd''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:237)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:214)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:364)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'null/ndk-build.cmd'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "null/ndk-build.cmd" (in directory "C:\Proyectos_STUDIO\UVCCamera-master\libuvccamera"): CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
    ... 9 more

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
16 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 13 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I added the SDK and NDK path in the local.properties file. It is point 5 in the readme instructions.

```
sdk.dir=/home/username/Android/Sdk
ndk.dir=/home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, windows path is different.
Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: This solution is not working . Please suggest to me another solution

Comment: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build.cmd'' at
This is telling me the NDK path is not set

Answer (score 0):

set this path

sdk.dir=/home/username/Android/Sdk
ndk.dir=/home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle

uncomment

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9

under
UVCCamera\libuvccamera\src\main\jni\Application.mk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be old but in my case on Android Studio (Windows), using [released 3.3.3](https://github.com/jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera/releases/tag/3.3.3) the build gets failed with the same error as yours.

After changing the file `local.properties` from

```
    # header note.
    #Fri Mar 31 14:42:53 HOVT 2023
    sdk.dir=D\:\\Programs\\AndroidSDK
```

to

```
    # header note.
    #Fri Mar 31 14:42:53 HOVT 2023
    sdk.dir=D\:\\Programs\\AndroidSDK
    ndk.dir=D\:\\Programs\\AndroidSDK\\ndk\\21.4.7075529
```

fix the problem and I was able to run the app.

**Note:**

1. Correct the path and check the NDK version you have in the folder `AndroidSDK\\ndk`
2. You don't have to comment `# NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9` in `\libuvc\src\main\jni\Application.mk` because in this version it already commented